# OSMF YouTube AS3 API

Tags: youtube-api, osmf

I'm working on an application that needs to load flvs as well as YouTube videos. I'm actually using OSMF and I'm trying to avoid having to duplicate functions by creating a YouTube component and a FLV component.

How would you go about it? Ideally, I'd like to end up with a YouTube class that extends MediaElement.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not looking for a full answer here :) Just a broad direction, I think it's possible to do it , any comments are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the source code of the YouTube OSMF plugin developed by the Flash/Strobe Media Playback team: http://sourceforge.net/adobe/smp/wiki/YouTube%20Plugin/

The plugin creates a YouTubeElement class which extends MediaElement, which uses the YouTube API.

-Andrian Cucu